# OCaml equivalent of Python generators

Tags: python, ocaml, generator

The french *Sécurité Sociale* identification numbers end with a check code of two digits. I have verified that every possible [common transcription error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit#Design) can be detected, and found some other kinds of errors (*e.g.*, rolling three consecutive digits) that may stay undetected.

```
def check_code(number):
    return 97 - int(number) % 97

def single_digit_generator(number):
    for i in range(len(number)):
        for wrong_digit in "0123456789":
            yield number[:i] + wrong_digit + number[i+1:]

def roll_generator(number):
    for i in range(len(number) - 2):
        yield number[:i] + number[i+2] + number[i] + number[i+1] + number[i+3:]
        yield number[:i] + number[i+1] + number[i+2] + number[i] + number[i+3:]

def find_error(generator, number):
    control = check_code(number)
    for wrong_number in generator(number):
        if number != wrong_number and check_code(wrong_number) == control:
            return (number, wrong_number)

assert find_error(single_digit_generator, "0149517490979") is None
assert find_error(roll_generator, "0149517490979") == ('0149517490979', '0149517499709')
```

My Python 2.7 code (working fragment above) makes heavy use of generators. I was wondering how I could adapt them in OCaml. I surely can write a function maintaining some internal state, but I'm looking for a purely functional solution. May I study the library [`lazy`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Lazy.html), which I'm not too familiar with? I'm not asking for code, just directions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may simply define a generator as a *stream*, using the extension of the language :

```
let range n = Stream.from (fun i -> if i < n then Some i else None);;
```

The `for` syntactic construct cannot be used with that, but there's a set of functions provided by the `Stream` module to check the state of the stream and iterate on its elements.

```
try
  let r = range 10 in
  while true do
    Printf.printf "next element: %d\n" @@ Stream.next r
  done
with Stream.Failure -> ();;
```

Or more simply:

```
Stream.iter (Printf.printf "next element: %d\n") @@ range 10;;
```

You may also use a special syntax provided by the *camlp4* preprocessor:

```
Stream.iter (Printf.printf "next element: %d\n") [< '11; '3; '19; '52; '42 >];;
```

Other features include creating streams out of lists, strings, bytes or even channels. The [API documentation](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stream.html)  succinctly describes the different possibilities.

The special syntax let you compose them, so as to put back elements before or after, but it can be somewhat unintuitive at first:

```
let dump = Stream.iter (Printf.printf "next element: %d\n");;

dump [< range 10; range 20 >];;
```

will produce the elements of the first stream, and then pick up the second stream at element ranked *right after* the rank of the last yielded element, thus it will appear in this case as if only the second stream got iterated.

To get all the elements, you could construct a stream of `'a Stream.t` and then recursively iterate on each:

```
Stream.iter dump [< '(range 10); '(range 20) >];;
```

These would produce the expected output.

I recommend reading the old book on OCaml (available [online](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/index.html)) for a better introduction on the topic.

Comment: the `Stream` module has been [deprecated](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.14.0) since OCaml `4.14.0` and removed from OCaml `5.0` onward

Answer (score 6):

[`Core`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core/) library provides generators in a python style, see [`Sequence`](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/111.28.00/doc/core_kernel/#Sequence) module.

Here is an example, taken from one of my project:

```
open Core_kernel.Std

let intersections tab (x : mem) : _ seq =
  let open Sequence.Generator in
  let init = return () in
  let m = fold_intersections tab x ~init ~f:(fun addr x gen ->
      gen >>= fun () -> yield (addr,x)) in
  run m
```

Comment: Any link? Do you speak of this [`Seq`](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview:batteries-beta1/html/api/Seq.html) module?

Comment: I've added links to the corresponding modules. `Seq` is just my own alias for `Sequence`. I've renamed it back. You may find more examples on provided links.

Comment: You might want to consider just opening Or_error.Monad_infix, rather than the whole Or_error module.  Generally better to open less rather than more...

Comment: actually, infixes here are from `Generaror` module, I've just grabbed this open accidentally from mine project, where `Or_error` is always opened, since we're using `Or_error` by default everywhere. I remove this open from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since [OCaml `4.07`](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.07.0) (released in 2018, and hence not available at the time the other answers were submitted), you can use the standard [`Seq`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) module:

```ml
let range (start : int) (end_ : int) : int Seq.t =
  let step = if end_ > start then +1 else -1 in 
  Seq.unfold (
    fun x -> if x = end_ then None else Some (x, x + step)
  ) start
;;

let numbers = range 4 (-7);;

Seq.iter (Printf.printf "%d ") numbers;;
```

Output: `4 3 2 1 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5 -6`

---

It is possible to transform sequences via `Seq.map`, `Seq.filter`, ...

Furthermore, OCaml 4.14 added [many functions](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html#1_Combiningsequences) to combine sequences, such as `Seq.zip`, `Seq.interleave`, `Seq.product`...

Demo:

```ml
let numbers_mul_by_3 = Seq.map (( * ) 3) (range 0 5);;
let chars = List.to_seq ['a'; 'b'; 'c'];;

let cartesian_product = List.sort compare
    (List.of_seq @@ Seq.product numbers_mul_by_3 chars)
;;

List.iter
    (fun (num, ch) -> Printf.printf "(%d, %c) " num ch)
    cartesian_product
;;
```

Output:
`(0, a) (0, b) (0, c) (3, a) (3, b) (3, c) (6, a) (6, b) (6, c) (9, a) (9, b) (9, c) (12, a) (12, b) (12, c)`

Comment: Why use `List.sort compare (List.of_seq @@ Seq.product numbers_mul_by_3 chars)` vs. `List.sort compare @@ List.of_seq @@ Seq.product numbers_mul_by_3 chars`? If you're going to use `@@`, might as well really use it.

Comment: @Chris feel free to edit the code as you see fit, I am only a dabbler in OCaml. I am not quite sure when it is idiomatic to use the function composition operators instead of parentheses.